# How to use global variable in oracle stored procedure for query

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures, global-variables

I have been provided global variables &S_NAME, &R_ID which i want to use in the oracle stored procedure for cursor query for `kpi_log` table. This global variable will fetch all required input values  from the `kpi_chk` table where i have column name and id and pass it to `kpi_log` table. I have not used global variable before and dont even know how to use it.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE TEST_CHK  
(IN_L_ID OUT NUMBER)   
AS   

CURSOR STA_CHECK IS  
Select NAME, ID FROM KPI_LOG where NAME = [here i have to use gloabal variable] and ID = [here i have to use gloabal variable];  


BEGIN    

... 


END TEST_CHK;
```

Comment: If you have a package declare a variable inside the package spec. It will be available for all procedures  OR you can give them as input parameters @andrew

Comment: so how do i define it in query in my procedure? i mean the syntax of using global variable in query

Comment: Do you  have a package? Then declare it as a normal varable

Comment: your variable will be global if you declare inside a package spec

Comment: actually the package is in production database so i cant see it but there this global variable has been defined i believe. Can you please give an example how to use it. Its really confusing for me.

Comment: yes i understood that but how can i use this variable in my select query ? For example &S_NAME, &R_ID i have this global variable provided. Do i need to assign '&' while using it and do i need to declare like normal variable and assign any value to it?

Comment: try the answer, if you have values in your variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have value in the variables, take it as input parameter

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE TEST_CHK  
(IN_L_ID OUT NUMBER, S_NAME VARCHAR2(50),R_ID VARCHAR2(50) )   
AS   

CURSOR STA_CHECK IS  
Select NAME, ID FROM KPI_LOG where NAME = S_NAME  and ID =R_ID;  

BEGIN    

... 


END TEST_CHK;
```

Comment: just a small question here can i declare like this also ? CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE TEST_CHK  
(IN_L_ID OUT NUMBER )   
AS   
S_NAME VARCHAR2(50); R_ID VARCHAR2(50);
CURSOR STA_CHECK IS  
Select NAME, ID FROM KPI_LOG where NAME = S_NAME  and ID =R_ID;  

BEGIN    

... 


END TEST_CHK

Comment: Yes you can, try it!

Comment: @Andrew Yes, you can just refer to the variable by name. If it is in another package you will need to include the package name using dot notation e.g. `otherpackage.somevar`. There is no prefix character like `@` or `&` for PL/SQL variables/constants/parameters.

Comment: just a small question if i create a procedure not defined inside package specification or package body then can i use this global variable with dot notation in my procedure ?

Comment: Yes @Andrew. As suggested use packagename.variablename